# Changing the formatting of sheets

Tags: performance, vba, excel

This my program to change the formatting of sheets in different folders. I have over 5000 files in one folder and it is taking up to three hrs for one folder and there are multiple subfolders in the main folder. I want to cut down this time to 10 mins or as fast as possible.

```
Sub loopAllSubFolderSelectStartDirectory()

'Another Macro must call LoopAllSubFolders Macro to start to procedure
Call LoopAllSubFolders("D:\HTTP\")

End Sub
'Don’t run the following macro, it will be called from the macro above:

'List all files in sub folders
Sub LoopAllSubFolders(ByVal folderPath As String)

Dim fileName As String
Dim fullFilePath As String
Dim numFolders As Long
Dim folders() As String
Dim i As Long

Set wc = ActiveWorkbook
If Right(folderPath, 1) <> "\" Then folderPath = folderPath & "\"
fileName = Dir(folderPath & "*.*", vbDirectory)

While Len(fileName) <> 0

    If Left(fileName, 1) <> "." Then

        fullFilePath = folderPath & fileName

        If (GetAttr(fullFilePath) And vbDirectory) = vbDirectory Then
            ReDim Preserve folders(0 To numFolders) As String
            folders(numFolders) = fullFilePath
            numFolders = numFolders + 1

        Else

Set wb = Workbooks.Open(fullFilePath)
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim fnd As Variant
Dim rplc As Variant

fnd = "<*>"
rplc = ""

For Each sht In wb.Worksheets
On Error GoTo 0
  sht.Cells.Replace what:=fnd, Replacement:=rplc, _
    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, _
    SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
    Next sht

Workbooks("New file to be saved.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:T1").Copy

'Now, paste to y worksheet:
wb.ActiveSheet.Range("A1").PasteSpecial
Range("G2:H100").Cut Range("Q2:R100")
Range("B2:F100").Cut Range("F2:J100")
wb.ActiveSheet.Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit

'With wb.ActiveSheet.Range("A1:T1").Interior
'        .Pattern = xlSolid
'        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
'        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
'        .TintAndShade = -0.149998474074526
'        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
'    End With
'    With wb.ActiveSheet.Range("A1:T1").Font
'        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight2
'        .TintAndShade = 0
'    End With
'    Range("A1:T1").Font.Bold = True


    wb.SaveAs Replace(wb.FullName, ".csv", ".xls"), FileFormat:=xlExcel8
wb.Close True
Kill fullFilePath
            'Insert the actions to be performed on each file
            'This example will print the full file path to the immediate window
            'Debug.Print folderPath & fileName

        End If

    End If
fileName = Dir()

Wend

For i = 0 To numFolders - 1

    LoopAllSubFolders folders(i)

Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Have you measured how much time a single sheet takes to reformat?

Comment: Are you modifying both Excel and CSV formats?  Or are you just converting CSV to `xls`?  Why are you using the older `xls` instead of the new `xlsx` format?

Comment: `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` is going to give you a massive boost in speed. [Optimize VBA Code to run Macros Faster](https://analysistabs.com/vba/optimize-code-run-macros-faster/).

Comment: where to place it

Comment: The first line of code will work.  There are other optimizations that can be made but it is hard to determine without sample files.

Comment: @MFaizanFarooq use @ and then the  person's username when replying to comments.

Comment: While `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` at the beginning of your code will certainly increase your execution speed, remember that most of your execution time will likely be outside of Excel's control: interacting with the file system. This is true particularly if some or all of the external files are located in a network folder. Also, Excel will take "X" amount of time to open another workbook, so that execution time can't be increased either.

Answer (score 3):

I use the following sub to speed up processing:

```
Public Sub AppSpeed(Optional iWhat As Long = xlDown)

    Dim bDir As Boolean

    bDir = True
    If iWhat = xlUp Then bDir = False

    On Error Resume Next

    With Application
         .Calculation = IIf(bDir, xlCalculationAutomatic, xlCalculationManual)
         .ScreenUpdating = bDir
         .DisplayStatusBar = bDir
         .EnableEvents = bDir
         .DisplayPageBreaks = bDir
         .PrintCommunication = bDir
   End With
End Sub
```

and I call it like

```
AppSpeed xlUp ' at the beginning of the app
```

and

```
AppSpeed xlDown  ' az the end of processing
```

The inconvenience of this solution is that you can't monitor what's happening so Dim a counter like filecounter and put the following snippet somewhere in the loop e.g. after `wb.SaveAs` to see that something is happening

```
    filecounter = filecounter + 1
    If 100 * (filecounter \ 100) = filecounter Then
        AppSpeed xlDown
        Application.StatusBar = folderpath & " " & CStr(filecounter)
        DoEvents
        AppSpeed xlUp
    End If
```

Next advice is to reduce the number of files in one folder. The documenations do not really help in this matter. My experience is that it is worth to keep the number of files under 1000 in one folder because access time increases enormously over that. You have a flexible structure so can quickly test it by dividing the files to multiple folders.

Comment: You might want to explain why the `With` statement helps speed up the execution.

Comment: @pacmaninbw One purpose of `With` is to simplify the syntax. In my example I could replace `Application.<property>` with <.property> with the help of the preceeding `With` statement 6 times. So what really speeds up the app is to disable a few automated operations of Excel like recalculating page breaks after a `.Cut` or a `.AutoFit` operation x10K times by issuing an `Application.DisplayPageBreaks = False` especially in those cases when it needs communication with the printer.

Comment: One use of `With` is to put the address of Application into a register and that speeds up the access of the member properties.