# Why does it take so long to print values from userform to sheet?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a userform with around 20 controls in that can be inputted. Some are textboxes some are comboboxes etc.

The user fills in these controls and then hits save. When save is pressed, the code finds the relevant row number (based on the task number generated in userform e.g. 1.04 will find 1.03 and add row below.)

However, it can take around 10 seconds or more to fill the newly inserted/copied row, which is impractical for something that will be used frequently.

Is there any efficiencies or alternatives i could use? Sorry I am a newbie to this sort of thing!

I have also included a screen shot which shows the user form, as well as the column where the value is searched before adding a row. The screenshot also shows example of the columns included in the spreadsheet.

[image: image 1]

[image: image 2]

[image: userform image]

```
Private Sub CommandButtonSave_Click()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlManual

'Declare variables
Dim subtaskws As Worksheet: Set subtaskws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sub Tasks")
Dim ActivityWs As Worksheet: Set ActivityWs = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Activity Overview")
Dim lastrow As Long, lastrowAO As Long, cellinput As Variant, newrow As Long, lastcollet As String, lastcol As Long, findtasknum As Range, lastrowST As Long, cell As Range, found As Variant, activitynum As Long

'Find column Letters
Call ColumnLetterFinder(subtaskws, 2, "Actual Workload", AWCol)
Call ColumnLetterFinder(subtaskws, 2, "W.", WCol)
Call ColumnLetterFinder(subtaskws, 2, "I.", ICol)
Call ColumnLetterFinder(subtaskws, 2, "E.", ECol)
Call ColumnLetterFinder(subtaskws, 2, "P", PCol)
Call ColumnLetterFinder(subtaskws, 2, "Level", LevelCol)

'find lastrows, columns and cells
lastrow = (subtaskws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row) + 1
lastcol = subtaskws.Cells(2, 1).End(xlToRight).Column
lastcollet = lastcol
lastcollet = Split(Cells(1, lastcol).Address, "$")(1)
lastrowST = subtaskws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
activitynum = AddTask.TextBoxid.Value + 1

Dim Ctrl As Variant, range1 As Range, userformorder As Variant, col As Long, IDrange() As Variant
userformorder = Array("SubTaskID", "TextBoxsubtask", "ComboBoxDeliverableFormat", "TextBoxcheckedcomplete", "TextBoxformat", "TextBoxacceptancecriteria", "BudgetWorkloadTextBox", "AWLTextBox", "ComboBoxOwner", "TextBoxTDSNumber", "TextBoxMilestone", "TextBoxTargetDeliveryDate", "ComboBoxW", "ComboBoxI", "ComboBoxe", "TextBoxP", "TextBoxLevel", "TextBoxInputQuality", "TextBoxNewInput", "TextBoxDelay", "TextBoxInternalVV", "TextBoxReviewer", "TextBoxDelivered", "ComboBoxNumIterations", "ComboBoxAcceptance", "ComboBoxProgress", "ComboBoxStatus", "ComboBoxFlowChart", "TextBoxActivitySheet", "TextBoxEvidenceofDelivery", "TextBoxComments") 'etc


'Find row before subtaskId number
Set found = subtaskws.Range("A3:A" & lastrowST).Find(What:=(activitynum), LookAt:=xlWhole)
If found Is Nothing Then
    newrow = lastrow

subtaskws.Range("A4:A" & lastcollet).EntireRow.Copy
subtaskws.Range("A" & newrow).EntireRow.PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats
subtaskws.Range("A" & newrow).EntireRow.PasteSpecial xlPasteValidation
subtaskws.Range("A" & newrow).EntireRow.PasteSpecial xlPasteAllMergingConditionalFormats
subtaskws.Range("A" & newrow & ":AE" & newrow & "").ClearContents
subtaskws.Columns("A:BB").Calculate

For Each Ctrl In userformorder
If col = 8 Then
Else
    If AddTask.Controls(Ctrl).Value <> "" Then
        subtaskws.Range("A" & newrow).Offset(, col).Value = AddTask.Controls(Ctrl).Value
    End If
col = col + 1
End If
Next Ctrl

subtaskws.Cells(newrow, AWCol).Value = "=SUM(AF" & newrow & ":" & lastcollet & newrow & ")"
subtaskws.Cells(newrow, PCol).Value = "=(" & WCol & newrow & "*" & ICol & newrow & "*" & ECol & newrow & ")"
subtaskws.Cells(newrow, LevelCol).Value = "=IF(" & PCol & newrow & " >11,1,IF(" & PCol & newrow & ">3,2,""N/A""))"

Else
    subtaskws.Range("A" & (found.row)).EntireRow.Insert
    newrow = found.row - 1
    subtaskws.Range("A4:A" & lastcollet & "").EntireRow.Copy
    subtaskws.Range("A" & newrow).EntireRow.PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats
    subtaskws.Range("A" & newrow).EntireRow.PasteSpecial xlPasteValidation
    subtaskws.Range("A" & newrow).EntireRow.PasteSpecial xlPasteAllMergingConditionalFormats
    subtaskws.Range("A" & newrow & ":AE" & newrow & "").ClearContents

For Each Ctrl In userformorder
    If AddTask.Controls(Ctrl).Value <> "" Then
        subtaskws.Range("A" & newrow).Offset(, col).Value = AddTask.Controls(Ctrl).Value
    End If
col = col + 1
Next Ctrl

subtaskws.Cells(newrow, AWCol).Value = "=SUM(AF" & newrow & ":" & lastcollet & newrow & ")"
subtaskws.Cells(newrow, PCol).Value = "=(" & WCol & newrow & "*" & ICol & newrow & "*" & ECol & newrow & ")"
subtaskws.Cells(newrow, LevelCol).Value = "=IF(" & PCol & newrow & " >11,1,IF(" & PCol & newrow & ">3,2,""N/A""))"

End If


    TextBoxsubtask.Value = vbNullString
    ComboBoxDeliverableFormat.Value = vbNullString
    TextBoxformat.Value = vbNullString
    ComboBoxOwner.Value = vbNullString
    TextBoxTargetDeliveryDate.Value = vbNullString
    ComboBoxW.Value = vbNullString
    ComboBoxI.Value = vbNullString
    ComboBoxe.Value = vbNullString
    TextBoxP.Value = vbNullString
    TextBoxLevel.Value = vbNullString
    TextBoxComments.Value = Null
    TextBoxEvidenceofDelivery.Value = Null
    TextBoxActivitySheet.Value = Null
    ComboBoxFlowChart.Value = Null
    ComboBoxStatus.Value = Null
    ComboBoxProgress.Value = Null
    ComboBoxAcceptance.Value = Null
    ComboBoxNumIterations.Value = Null
    TextBoxDelivered.Value = Null
    TextBoxReviewer.Value = Null
    TextBoxInternalVV.Value = Null
    TextBoxDelay.Value = Null
    TextBoxNewInput.Value = Null
    TextBoxInputQuality.Value = Null
    TextBoxMilestone.Value = Null
    TextBoxTDSNumber.Value = Null
    TextBoxacceptancecriteria.Value = Null
    TextBoxcheckedcomplete.Value = Null
    SubTaskID.Value = SubTaskID.Value + 0.01

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic

End Sub



Public Function ColumnLetterFinder(ws, row, Value, x)

Dim rFind As range

          With ws.Rows(row)
                Set rFind = .Find(What:=Value, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
                If Not rFind Is Nothing Then
                      x = Split(rFind.Address, "$")(1)
                End If
            End With

End Function
```

Comment: You should include `ColumnLetterFinder` and some screenshots of thedata and  formats.  I download link with mock data would also help.

Comment: Sorry these have been added now!

Comment: Sorry about the slow response.  Is `ColumnLetterFinder()` really necessary?  Will the users be reordering the columns?  Or are you using it to make your code more dynamic, in case you plan on changing the column order yourself?

Comment: Yes unfortunately as the extra columns may be added in depending on the project. The columns included now and the vital ones

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong so just a few shots in the dark:

Are there any "hidden" data-driven automations like worksheet_change or whatever?

You may disable event handling and a few more time comsuming services for the course of processing. Take a look at this: [Speed up App](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/234904/changing-the-formatting-of-sheets/235074?noredirect=1#comment459911_235074)

I would not apply copying validations and formats and whatever on all the 16K cells in the entire row. It's OK to manage a dynamically changing number of columns but I'd rather maximize the number of columns with calculating the exact number of used columns (more hassle) or simply setting it to say 100 if you'd never have more than 80 (quick and dirty).

Checking a string for zero length it is somewhat faster to use

```
If LenB(AddTask.Controls(Ctrl).Value) <> 0 ...
```

instead of

```
If AddTask.Controls(Ctrl).Value <> "" ...
```

for it does not invoke string comparision function but checks a single byte in the string header.

+1: For manipulating formulas run-time I prefer using `.Cells` this way

```
subtaskws.FormulaLocal="=sum(" & Range(CElls(newrow, "AF"), Cells(newrow, lastcollet)).Address & ")"
```

for it is more handy than bothering with string concatenations to make cell references. 
See also `.FormulaLocal` and `.Address(False, False)`

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! i never knew about forumla local so that could be really handy! thanks

Answer (score 1):

I am going to address some style issues.

**Do not compress lines**

Yes, the syntax allows you to write code like:

```
Dim subtaskws As Worksheet: Set subtaskws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sub Tasks")
```

But it is harder to read and the assignment versus declaration is harder to see. This makes code harder to follow and maintain. Instead, be clear and explicit:

```
Dim subtaskws As Worksheet 
Set subtaskws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sub Tasks")
```

The use of the ':' is useful in command line basic (or when doing some things in the immediate window). It is not good in modules.

**Use code names (named sheets)**

In the VBA Editor, you can rename the 'Sheet1' name of the sheets to something meaningful. Let us say, for example, that you change the `(Name)` of the sheets to 'SubTasks'. The following image is an example I have - different names but you should get the idea.

[image]

Now the code

```
Dim subtaskws As Worksheet 
Set subtaskws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sub Tasks")
```

is no longer necessary, and you can jump straight into

```
lastcol = SubTasks.Cells(2, 1).End(xlToRight).Column
```

**Do not use `Call`**

This is debated - `Call` is an obsolete word for backwards compatibility, but if anyone needs backwards compatibility to when Call was necessary, they have much bigger issues!

But you have really exemplified why using the obsolete and unnecessary token is not good. You have completely misused a function call (see next comment)!

At this point I am going to say:

```
Call ColumnLetterFinder(subtaskws, 2, "Actual Workload", AWCol)
```

should be idiomatic VBA:

```
ColumnLetterFinder subtaskws, 2, "Actual Workload", AWCol
```

**Functions should return things**

Your function, written as a `Function` does not return anything. From your description it is intended to return a string representing the name of a column. There are other ways of doing this, or achieving the result you want. But, for the purposes of this answer I am going to focus on the Function.

```
Public Function ColumnLetterFinder(ws, row, Value, x)
```

does not declare a return type, does not strongly type the inputs, nor does it exercise discipline in mutating values (by value, rather than by the implicit reference).

```
Public Function ColumnLetterFinder(ByVal ws As Worksheet, ByVal row As Long, ByVal Value As String, ByRef x As String) As String
```

Note: I made the last one explicitly `ByRef` because your current code changes that value.

Of course, what you are implicitly doing, is returning the answer through `x`. So, we can tidy this up a bit:

```
Public Function ColumnLetterFinder(ByVal ws As Worksheet, ByVal row As Long, ByVal Value As String) As String
Dim rFind As range
      With ws.Rows(row)
            Set rFind = .Find(What:=Value, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
            If Not rFind Is Nothing Then
                  ColumnLetterFinder = Split(rFind.Address, "$")(1) '<--- set the return value here
            End If
        End With
End Function ' Default value for string is "" if rFind is nothing
```

Now your main code can definitely get rid of that annoying `Call`:

```
AWCol = ColumnLetterFinder(subtaskws, 2, "Actual Workload")
```

… or if you have names the sheet as suggested before:

```
AWCol = ColumnLetterFinder(SubTasks, 2, "Actual Workload")
```

Now the code pretty much comments itself!

**Standard comments**

Use `Option Explict` at the top of modules. Always. ***Always***.

Properly indent your code. This makes it easier to read and easier to spot where logic should be. An out of place `If` or loop becomes easier to spot.

Use meaningful variable names every time. Yes, it is sometimes hard to figure out a good name, but you will thank yourself in the months to come. After all, what did 'x' mean?