# Edit Excel through MS Access

Tags: performance, vba, excel, ms-access

I have an Access macro that runs `AfterUpdate` of a form. It opens an Excel workbook and edits a few cells. I have It working the way I want, but the problem is that the code takes about 25 seconds to run. This is way too long for the users of this database to have to wait. After adding some timing messages, I found that 98% of that time is just spent opening and saving Excel.

I have a few ideas on how to fix this problem. I'm hoping someone out there can tell which are possible/which is the best way to approach the problem:

1. Create a CSV file next to the workbook. Access adds the 5 values to the CSV file each time the macro runs. Then I add `Workbook_Open` macro to the Workbook that reads the CSV file and makes the changes, then clears the CSV.
2. Add a new table to my access file that keeps track of the form updates that have been made. Then, when the access file is closed or saved, another macro opens the Excel workbook, makes the changes and clears the new table.
3. (pie in sky idea, not sure how to do this) Somehow open the workbook in the background and pass the 5 values to it, so that an Excel macro makes the changes without causing Access to freeze while the code runs.
4. (last resort idea, really don't want to do this) Import the workbook into the Access file so the changes can be made without involving Excel.

Here's the current code:

````vb
Option Compare Database

Const xlToRight As Long = -4161
Const xlToLeft As Long = -4159
Const xlUp As Long = -4162
Const xlDown As Long = -4121

Private Sub Form_AfterUpdate()
'This macro will update the Excel WO Tracker for a project each time an NCR is closed or resolved

Dim xl As Object 'Excel
Dim tracker As Object 'Book
Dim sn As Object 'Sheet
Dim wo As Object, scrap As Object, wos As Object, cell As Object 'Range
Dim connect(1) As Variant 'WO and NCR#
Dim assy() As Variant 'Part and associated WO's
Dim partName As String, NCR As String
Dim starttime As Double

'Exit if required fields are blank
starttime = Timer
If (Title.Value = "") Or (status.Value = "") Or (Program.Value = "") Or _
    (Disposition.Value = "") Or ([Work Order Number].Value = "") Then
    Exit Sub
End If
On Error GoTo Handler

If (status.Value = "Closed") Or (status.Value = "Resolved") Then
    Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    xl.ScreenUpdating = False
    Select Case Program.Value
    Case "SE07"
        Set tracker = xl.Workbooks.Open("Z:\Operations\Projects\Sierra\SE07\" & Year(Now()) & " SE07 WO Tracker.xlsm")
    Case "VS02"
        Set tracker = xl.Workbooks.Open("Z:\Operations\Projects\ViaSat\VS01\" & Year(Now()) & " VS02 WO Tracker.xlsm")
    Case Else 'Program does not have a WO Tracker
        xl.ScreenUpdating = True
        Set xl = Nothing
        Exit Sub
    End Select
    
    Set sn = tracker.Sheets("SN")
        'Record NCR connection
        connect(0) = [Work Order Number].Value
        connect(1) = Title.Value
        xl.Intersect(sn.Range("NCRConnect"), sn.Columns(xl.Intersect(sn.Range("FirstCol"), sn.Range("NCRConnect")).End(xlToRight).Column + 1)) = xl.Transpose(connect)
            
    Set wo = sn.UsedRange.Find([Work Order Number].Value)
    If Not wo Is Nothing Then
        If (Disposition.Value = "Scrap-Destroy") Or (Disposition.Value = "Scrap-Repurpose") Then 'Move WO to scrap graveyard
            If xl.Intersect(wo, sn.Range("ScrapYard")) Is Nothing Then
                If xl.Intersect(wo, sn.Range("Layup")) Is Nothing Then
                    partName = sn.Cells(wo.Row, 1).End(xlUp).Value
                    'Copy From
                    If xl.Intersect(wo.Offset(-1, 0), sn.Range("EmptyRows")) Is Nothing Then
                        If xl.Intersect(wo.Offset(1, 0), sn.Range("EmptyRows")) Is Nothing Then
                            Set wo = sn.Range(sn.Cells(sn.Cells(wo.Row, 1).End(xlUp).Row, wo.Column), sn.Cells(sn.Cells(wo.Row, 1).End(xlDown).Row, wo.Column))
                        Else 'wo is at bottom of range
                            Set wo = sn.Range(sn.Cells(sn.Cells(wo.Row, 1).End(xlUp).Row, wo.Column), wo)
                        End If
                    Else 'wo is at top of range
                        Set wo = sn.Range(wo, sn.Cells(sn.Cells(wo.Row, 1).End(xlDown).Row, wo.Column))
                    End If
                    assy = wo
                    'Copy To
                    Set scrap = sn.Cells(sn.Range("ScrapYard").Find(partName).Row, sn.Range("ScrapYard").Find("NCRs").End(xlToRight).Column + 1).Resize(wo.Rows.Count, 1)
                    scrap = assy
                    wo.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
                    'Record NCR#
                    Set wo = sn.Cells(xl.Max(sn.Cells(sn.Range("NCRConnect").Row, scrap.Column).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row, sn.Range("ScrapYard").Find("NCRs").Row), scrap.Column)
                    wo.Value = Title.Value
                    Set wos = xl.Intersect(sn.Range("ScrapYard"), sn.Columns(wo.Column))
                    For Each cell In wos
                        Set scrap = sn.Rows(sn.Range("NCRConnect").Row).Find(cell.Value)
                        If (Not scrap Is Nothing) And (InStr(cell.Value, Program.Value) <> 0) Then
                            NCR = scrap.Offset(1, 0).Value
                            Set scrap = wos.Find(NCR)
                            If scrap Is Nothing Then
                                Set wo = wo.Offset(1, 0)
                                wo.Value = NCR
                            End If
                        End If
                    Next cell
                Else
                    partName = sn.Cells(wo.Row, 1).Value
                    Set scrap = sn.Cells(sn.Range("ScrapYard").Find(partName).Row, sn.Range("ScrapYard").Find("NCRs").End(xlToRight).Column + 1)
                    scrap = wo.Value
                    wo.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
                    Set wo = sn.Cells(xl.Max(sn.Cells(sn.Range("NCRConnect").Row, scrap.Column).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row, sn.Range("ScrapYard").Find("NCRs").Row), scrap.Column)
                    wo.Value = Title.Value
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If
End If

tracker.Save
tracker.Close
Set tracker = Nothing
Set sn = Nothing
xl.ScreenUpdating = True
Set xl = Nothing
Debug.Print Round(Timer - starttime, 2) & " seconds"
Exit Sub

Handler:
tracker.Save
tracker.Close
Set tracker = Nothing
Set sn = Nothing
xl.ScreenUpdating = True
Set xl = Nothing

End Sub
```
````

Comment: I/O is going to be hopelessly slow indeed, with little to no opportunity to improve... is `Z:` a mapped network drive? Is there a way the Access database / backend could be on the same server? Curious how much of that 25 seconds gets shaved when the file is local..

Comment: Does the form's `AfterUpdate` method need to run more than once per form instance? Your point/idea #2 seems to mean the answer is "yes" - consider opening the workbook (hidden so user can't accidentally close it) with the form, and only closing it *with the form*?

Comment: Lastly... any reason why the workbook can't just *query* the Access db to get what it needs?

Comment: @ Mathieu Guindon Both files are on the same network drive, I can't move them to my computer because other employees use the database. I dont need it to happen `AfterUpdate`, but that was the easiest way I could figure out when I started writing this macro. I've considered having Excel look into the database, I just don't know a lot about Access so that would take a lot of research

Comment: If the db and the xlsx are on the same machine, try accessing the xlsx with a local path instead of a mapped network drive.

Comment: Assigning value to `Object` `scrap` (at two points) without `Set` is a bit suspicious. Doesn't it take you to the error handler? BTW right after assigning value to it with `Set`. I'd further refine time analysis by more measurements. You could keep reducing run time by disabling event handling and a few more time comsuming services for the course of processing. Take a look at this: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/234904/changing-the-formatting-of-sheets/235074?noredirect=1#comment459911_235074 . You needn't even waste time with restoring the settings if you close Excel anyway.